# Why PATCH is not part of the list of standard HTTP verbs (RFC 7231)

Tags: rest, api, http, methods, patch

PATCH is defined as standard in RFC5789 that appeared in 2010. However, RFC 7231 that appeared in 2014 does not add PATCH to standard HTTP verbs. Why ?

Comment: `PATCH` is mentioned in partial updates for [PUT](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4). It is probably not added because it is already specified in its own RFC. You might extend your question and also ask why non of the WebDAV operations was added to HTTP as well as according to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) they are part of HTTP as well?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really need to be in RFC7231. The fact that it doesn't appear in the base specification, does not really mean it's not standard.

The full list of standard methods can be found on the IANA page:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml